# How do i find the big O notation

Tags: algorithm

```
int something = 0 ;
int t = n ;

while ( t > 1 ) {
   for (int i=0 ; i < t ; i++) {
      something++ ;
   }
   t = t / 2 ;
} 
//number 2
int sum = 0; 
int i = 1; 

while (sum <= n) { 
    sum = sum + i; 
    i++; 
}
```

How do I find the tightest upper bound in big O notation. I think they would both be log n but I am not sure if the for loop in the first segment of code affects its run time significantly.

Comment: Neither is log(n). You must reexamine the method you used to reach that conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of the above code is **`O(n)`**.

Let's calculate the complexity of ***first part*** of the program.

```
int t = n;
while ( t > 1 ) {
   for (int i=0 ; i < t ; i++) {
      something++ ;
   }
   t = t / 2 ;
}
```

This will execute: `t + t/2 + t/4 + ... + 1`
and the sum of this series is `2t - 1`. (Refer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401937/how-is-nn-2n-4-1-equal-to-2n-1-using-the-formula-for-geometric-series)).

Therefore, the time complexity of the first part if `O(2t - 1) = O(t)` or **O(n)**.

For ***second part***:

```
int sum = 0; 
int i = 1; 
while (sum <= n) { 
    sum = sum + i; 
    i++; 
}
```

*Sum* will be `1+2+3+....i` which is `i*(i+1)/2`.

So `sum =i*(i+1)/2` ~ **`i`<sup>2</sup>**

Also `sum <= n`

So `i`<sup>2</sup> <= `n` 
or `i` ~ [image: d]

Therfore the complexity of second part is **O([image: d])**

So the complexity of program is:
**T(n): O(n) + O([image: d]) = O(n)**

Overall complexity is **`O(n)`**